# Вживання слова "листівка" у значенні "фотографія"

Tags: вибір-слова

Неодноразово бачу в інтернеті використання слова ***листівка*** у значенні *фотографія*, причому як «друковане фото», так навіть і «цифрове фото». Ось нещодавно бачив використання у соцмережі:

> Привіт, а ти бачив свіжі *листівки* з [зі святкування] Дня Валентина?

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/lystivka) і інші словники дають лише значення «поштова картка». Є також багато комерційних сервісів, які пропонують друк *листівок*, саме у значенні «поштова/подарункова картка» або навіть [*відкритка*](http://www.postcard-ua.com/).

**Запитання. Чи є такий вжиток усталеним і, якщо так, які існують межі його вживання?**

Comment: Вперше бачу таке. Набагато частіше вживається слово *світлина*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

У друкованому варіанті [Академічного тлумачного словника](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D1%83_20_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85) зазначається, що слово "листівка" вживається виключно у значенні:

- "відкритка" (калька з рос. "откритка")
- рукописний листок агітаційного змісту

Тобто те ж, що ви і згадали.

Є ще фотолистівка: коли, наприклад, художньо оформили знімок відомого співака тощо. Тобто, коли в основі листівки - [фото](http://photo-lviv.in.ua/staryj-lviv-u-lystivkah/). Однак, це лише вид оформлення відкритки, як сказано у наведеному вами ресурсі:

> Поштова картка, іноді з малюнком з одного боку, для відкритого листа.

Тому, вважаю вживання цього слова *виключно* у значенні "фото" хибним.